# Localhost arduino pincontrol

Tags: webserver, arduino, controls

I want to make a browser-controlled Arduino, that can control 2 motors. The requrements for this, is that i want to be able to click on a button on the server that the Arduino hostes, and handle that input as if there was a button connected directly on the Arduino. Is that even possible ? 
I have looked at the example called TempretureWebPanel([Arduino Tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TemperatureWebPanel)), but that makes no sense to me.. 
Can someone please tell me where to find a tutorial for this, or even better, give an example of this.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to control an Arduino from a PC.

It uses C# on the PC side but you could drive it with any code you want as long as it supports writing to a USB/com port.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Csharp/SerialCommsCSharp#.UzK-F_l_t2c

Comment: But the goal with this, is to get it working in the browser. Because I want this to be accessible on cross-platform.

Comment: Then you should check out this for the browser part and use the above for the Arduino comms.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142955/is-there-a-way-to-communicate-with-usb-devices-from-browser

Comment: Look, I want to connect to the arduino via arduino.local/something, and from there, controle a motor via some clickble pic's.

Comment: Yes, I understand that and that is what I am trying to help you with.

Comment: I was not trying to sound rude. I'm sorry. I know you are only trying to help.

Comment: That's OK I was writing more but Stack cut me off so it looks like I was annoyed when I'm not. Full comment is below

Comment: Yes, I understand that and that is what I am trying to help you with.  I suspect you may have an incorrect idea about what browsers do.  The browser is just the User Interface.  It passes information back to a "backend" application that, in this case, does the actual work of talking to the Arduino.  You could write a browser plugin that takes the place of the backend code but you will need one for each browser type (Chrome, Safari etc)

Comment: Ohh okay, no problem :-)

Comment: Hi, I think i found a solution to my problem: http://scuola.arduino.cc/lesson/zzdeJ3m/YunServer_Sensor_values_to_HTML_page  But thanks for your help @richard210363